# Eclipse PyDev finds nonexisting errors due to pysvn's dynamic imports

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pysvn

I use `pysvn` as a part of a Eclipse PyDev project. The following code causes PyDev to complain:

```
import pysvn
pysvn.ClientError
#     ~~~~~~~~~~~ <= Undefined variable from import: ClientError
```

But it runs just fine, and this works:

```
>>> import pysvn
>>> pysvn.ClientError
<class 'pysvn._pysvn_2_7.ClientError'>
```

I'm rather sure the cause is the following piece of code in [`pysvn.py`](http://pysvn.tigris.org/source/browse/pysvn/trunk/pysvn/Extension/Source/pysvn/__init__.py.template?revision=1331&view=markup):

```
# ...

elif maj_min == (2,7):
    import _pysvn_2_7
    _pysvn = _pysvn_2_7

# ...

for key, value in _pysvn.__dict__.items():
    if not key.startswith( '__' ):
        globals()[ key ] = value
```

Somehow this throws PyDev off. (And no wonder, I'm thinking. Did they *have* to do it this way?)

I realize I can just do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and select `@UndefinedVariable` on each occurance of "undefined varaible", but I had hoped there was a more general solution.

My question: how do I fix this problem in

**1)** the most permanent way (for Everybody, not just me)

and

**2)** the most practical way (for me)

In case it matters, I'm using PyDev 2.4.0.2012020116 on Eclipse 3.7.2.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably add it to the forced built-ins, like described [here](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html).

If that doesn't work, you can disable this error in PyDev's settings through Editor>Code Analysis>Undefined

Comment: Adding to built-ins doesn't fix the problem. Your second suggestion works, but I *am* interested in getting the legitimate `Undefined variable from import` errors and this will turn them off as well. I'd rather turn off the known cases individually with `@UndefinedVariable` than disable the error entirely.

Comment: Sometimes adding to the built-ins needs some time, around 10-30 seconds usually. Also note that pydev will normally reanalyse your code only after you save, so code a few minutes and give it a chance :)

Comment: Went to Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python > Forced Builtins > New and typed `pysvn`. OK and Apply and OK. Change file and save it a couple of times. Wait a while. Change more things, save again. No effect.

Comment: :/ maybe upgrading pydev will help?

Comment: I've added pysvn to my "forced builtins" list as mentioned in this post and it worked perfectly.